# How to remove sharp rectangle edges from UIButton control?

Tags: ios, xcode4

Take a look at the following image:

[image]

As you can see the edges are sharp rectangle and they are coming out of the rounded corner button. How can I not show the edges and only show the round button?

UPDATE (Solution):

I used the following code to achieve the round corners:

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.stopButton.bounds 
                                       byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners  
                                       cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(12.0, 12.0)];

// Create the shape layer and set its path
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = self.stopButton.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
// Set the newly created shape layer as the mask for the image view's layer
self.stopButton.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

NEW PROBLEM:

This code gives me the error on the startButtonRound.layer.cornerRadius line.

```
  UIButton *roundStartButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
        roundStartButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 20); 
        [roundStartButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"green_gradient.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

        roundStartButton.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0; 
 UIBarButtonItem *startButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:roundStartButton];
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could do this with CALayer alone:

```
CALayer *myLayer = [CALayer layer];
[myLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[myLayer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
[myLayer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[myLayer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[myLayer setBackgroundColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
```

You'll also want to include the QuartzCore framework and include the frameworks header in your own.

```
#include <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Hope this helps

Tim

Comment: I did try [button layer] setCornerRadius:5.0f]; but it did not have any effect on the button.

Comment: You may need to set MasksToBounds to yes to get the layer to clip its contents to the rounded corners.

Comment: Does the UIButton have to be declared as an IBOutlet for the cornerRadius to work? See the original post updated problem.

Comment: No the layer property should work fine as all UIView derived controls in UIKit are layer (CALayer) backed. Could you provide the error itself?

Comment: Here is the error:  Property 'cornerRadius' cannot be found in forward class object 'CALayer *'

Comment: Have you added the QuartzCore framework to your project? If not you'll need to do so and then include <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> in your header.

Comment: You may want to set this as an answer so others can see the notes about QuartzCore.

Answer (score 5):

I think all that can be accomplished with:

```
self.stopButton.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0;
```

But did you try

```
self.stopButton.opaque = NO;
self.stopButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

?

Comment: Thanks Bill! That worked out great! I am not sure what I did but now even without the cornerRadius It was not showing the edges. But your code removed my 5-6 lines of code so thanks!

Comment: The UIButton.layer.cornerRadius does not work for me. It returns an error but setting backgroundColor to clear and set opaque to NO does it.

Comment: @Yko, Are you literally using `UIButton.layer.cornerRadius`?  That's (trying to) accessing the class, not an instance of the class.

Comment: @bshirley. No. I have a UIButton *btn = alloc...then I type btn.layer.cornerRadius.

Comment: @Yko then the error you likely are getting is caused by the need for `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: @bshirley. Hahaha. Wow! Good call. I haven't tried it but I'm sure you are right. Totally forgot that...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

form the look of the image you have set your UIButton bckground color to 'White'. Make it 'Clear Color'.